# Getting the length of an element of type sometype[] in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having difficulties getting the length of a typescript array. Here is what I did:

First, I am reading two local json files

```
let imagessObservable = this._http.get(this._imagesUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <string[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);

        let songsObservable = this._http.get(this._songsUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <string[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

then I try to combine both arrays:

```
Observable.zip(imagessObservable, songsObservable,
            (images, songs) =>
                this.CombineImagesAndSongs(images, songs));
```

where the CombineImagesAndSongs method is the following:

```
private CombineImagesAndSongs
        (images: string[], songs: string[]): Slide[] {
        let slides: Slide[] = [];

        for (let i = 0; i <images.length; i++) {

            slides[i] = new Slide(images[i], songs[i]);
        }
        return slides;
    }
```

when I debug the code I see that the loop only runs once, while the actual length of the images array is much longer.

When I write `images.length` in the console I get "undefined".

Why is this happening and how do I get the length property I need ? I thought that an object of type T[] in typescript has the length property - it does compiles and since typescript is type safe I find it strange that there is some runtime error like this

Comment: Well, TypeScript can only verify that the *compile time types* are correct, not that the runtime *values* are correct. In this case, if your http call returns `undefined`, or some other type that does not have a `length` property, TypeScript's out of the picture.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I am casting the returned json into string[] and the casting works (that is I verified the value in the debugger and if the casting were to fail I wouldn't expect the code to get to the method who receives the two string[] parameters) , so it still looks strange to me

Comment: You're not actually casting anything in the runtime JavaScript though. You're just telling the TypeScript compiler that you *expect* the value to be a string array. There's nothing stopping it from being anything else.

Comment: please use debugger and break point to watch "images.length" because it is input variable of function and you couldn`t watch it in console by command.